# python: converting corrupt xls file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I have downloaded few sales dataset from a SAP application. SAP has automatically converted the data to .XLS file. Whenever I open it using `Pandas` library I am getting the following error:

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '\xff\xfe\r\x00\n\x00\r\x00'
```

When I opened the .XLS file using MSEXCEL it is shows a popup saying that the `file is corrupt or unsupported extension do you want to continue` when I clicked 'Yes' its showing the correct data. When I saved the file again as .xls using msexcel I am able to use it using `Pandas`.

So, I tried renaming the file using `os.rename()` but it dint work. I tried opening the file and removing `\xff\xfe\r\x00\n\x00\r\x00`, but then also it dint work.

The solution is to open MSEXCEL and save the file again as .xls manually, is there any way to automate this. Kindly help.

Comment: I have checked the question, and my question is about converting it to another format.

Comment: @downshift No the file is not open in MS Excel.

Comment: I just want to do something similar to MS Excel `save-as`, but not manually. Is there any way?

Comment: Have you tried opening it using an encoding? E.g. df=pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx',encoding='utf-16le'). As per this link, that header is UTF-16 Little Endian: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2003-September/203525.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I converted the corrupt `.xls` to a correct `.xls` file. The following is the code:

```
# Changing the data types of all strings in the module at once
from __future__ import unicode_literals
# Used to save the file as excel workbook
# Need to install this library
from xlwt import Workbook
# Used to open to corrupt excel file
import io

filename = r'SALEJAN17.xls'
# Opening the file using 'utf-16' encoding
file1 = io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-16")
data = file1.readlines()

# Creating a workbook object
xldoc = Workbook()
# Adding a sheet to the workbook object
sheet = xldoc.add_sheet("Sheet1", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
# Iterating and saving the data to sheet
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    # Two things are done here
    # Removeing the '\n' which comes while reading the file using io.open
    # Getting the values after splitting using '\t'
    for j, val in enumerate(row.replace('\n', '').split('\t')):
        sheet.write(i, j, val)

# Saving the file as an excel file
xldoc.save('myexcel.xls')

import pandas as pd
df = pd.ExcelFile('myexcel.xls').parse('Sheet1')
```

No errors.

Comment: I have used the same code and I got the following error:    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: illegal UTF-16 surrogate

Comment: I got the same error, did it solve the problem, it sucks. :(

Comment: It worked for me after changing
file1 = io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-16") to 
file1 = io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8")

Maybe, you need to change the encoding as per your requirements in addition to the code above

Answer (score 2):

The other way to solve this problem is using win32com.client library:

```
import win32com.client
import os

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
o.Visible = False

filename = os.getcwd() + '/' + 'SALEJAN17.xls'
output = os.getcwd() + '/' + 'myexcel.xlsx'

wb = o.Workbooks.Open(filename)
wb.ActiveSheet.SaveAs(output,51)
```

In my example you save to .xlsx format but you can save as .xls as well.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Jeril's answer, we can skip the saving file process and load it directly to pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
    

import pandas as pd
import io

file_path = 'data/some_file.xls'

# Load the file with utf-16 encoding
with io.open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-16") as file1:
    data = file1.readlines()

# Split values by tab and create a DataFrame
data_list = [row.replace('\n', '').split('\t') for row in data]

# Extract column names (first list in the data_list)
column_names = data_list[0]

# Create a DataFrame using the remaining rows and column names
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list[1:], columns=column_names)
display(df)
```