# How to load xls file via pandas library in Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have got a problem with reading xls file via pandas.

```
 import pandas as pd 
 # name of file 
 name = "base.xls"
 wb = pandas.read_excel(name)
```

and it returns  the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jarze/PycharmProjects/CSV-modifier/venv/JustTry.py", line 4, in <module>
    wb = pandas.read_excel(name)
  File "C:\Users\jarze\PycharmProjects\CSV-modifier\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\jarze\PycharmProjects\CSV-modifier\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 824, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "C:\Users\jarze\PycharmProjects\CSV-modifier\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 21, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\jarze\PycharmProjects\CSV-modifier\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\jarze\PycharmProjects\CSV-modifier\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 36, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\jarze\PycharmProjects\CSV-modifier\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 148, in open_workbook
    bk = book.open_workbook_xls(
  File "C:\Users\jarze\PycharmProjects\CSV-modifier\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 92, in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
  File "C:\Users\jarze\PycharmProjects\CSV-modifier\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1278, in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
  File "C:\Users\jarze\PycharmProjects\CSV-modifier\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1272, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\xef\xbb\xbf<meta'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any hint as regards what I should do or how I could debug the error?

Comment: Are you sure that the file you're opening isn't corrupt as the error-message says?

Comment: Okay, it's automatically generated and it's corrupt but when i click that I am sure to still open it its working fine. How could i solve this through python?

Comment: I would try to work out why the automatically generated becomes corrupt in the first place. However, if that is not an option, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43995077/8805293) could help you further. If there is only a couple of files however, opening up the file itself and saving it as a non-corrupt .xls file would be advisable.

Comment: It seems that your generator creates an XML file with an UTF8 BOM marker. That is not what the excel reader expects. You should review your generation process or write a parser for that XML format.

Comment: When I use code from Hampus Larsson post I have got an "UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM" error and that's not possible to change generation process