# How to fix format and extension of "file_name.xls" don't match using python?

Tags: python, excel

How to fix error:

```
The file format and extension of "file_name.xls" don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?
```

I want to repair it via Python. When I am trying to repair it this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985768/python-converting-corrupt-xls-file), its return this kind of error:

```
in _buffer_decode
    raise UnicodeError("UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM")
UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM
```

I aim to input this file to pandas library.

Comment: I'd start by figuring out what format the file actually is.  apparently it's not XLS nor UTF-16, but that still leaves every other file type as a possibility.  Most Unix systems have a `file` command that you can use to figure this out, but presumably you're under Windows which is less helpful.  maybe you could use an online tool instead?

Comment: Okay, I check it out through HxD & List of file signature method and find out that this file is UTF-8 coded and finally when I substitute UTF-16 for UTF-8 its works and create file that is opening without any error. But the problem is that now it's doesn't look like a database at all. Its look more like some html code with a lot of <> </> stuff. Is there any posibility that i will make a database for pandas use out of it?

Comment: if it looks like HTML then I'd suggest opening it in a web browser (maybe after renaming to have a `.html` extension) and seeing what's in it.  you might well have the wrong thing saved

Comment: I figure it out a little bit from yesterday and now i know that if i manually copy all content from new xls file and paste it to notepad and save it as html I could open it on Chrome and it's look perfect but still don't know how to open it on pandas so I can manipulate data.

Comment: why not just save the file normally in Excel and use `pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')`?